# Вопрос по JAVADOC Comments в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Хочу чтобы IntelliJ IDEA автоматически генерировала при создании в пределах одного проекта коммментарии в шапке каждого нового класса/интерфейса примерно следующего вида:

```
/**
*
* @date: YYYY/MM/DD   (Дата создания)
*
* @autor: /name/
*
**/
```

Где и как такое можно настроить?